# Kendo ui angular 2 grid Server side filtering

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Is it possible to do server side filtering using Kendo ui angular 2 grid?
Can someone provide an example to do it?

Comment: you have to pass the amount of data you want back and how many in to the data it is. IE if you want items 11-20, you need to tell the server to skip the first 10 entries and pass you the next 10

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Thanks for the reply. Can you help us with any example code?

Comment: if you add the dataStateChange event to your grid and code, it will provide the current state of the grid when you change anything. This allows you to send over the grid's state to the server and you can then return the appropriate data